# Renaming files while keeping portions

Tags: files, rename

I need to rename portions of a number of files while keeping the IP address that's in the filenames.

For example,

```
Abc_192.168.1.164_001.txt
Abc_10.11.76.112_001.txt
Abc_54.78.1.1_002.txt
```

I need to keep the "Abc_" portion as well as the IP address. Everything after is to be replaced with a date and time stamp.  I would be adding the current date and time stamp as "_yymmdd-yymmdd-hhmmss" and we will be changing the extension to ".csv". This will run on Linux.

Comment: what kind of date and time stamp? and what about the ".txt" part?

Comment: Apologies, I should have clarified. I would be adding the current date and time stamp as "_yymmdd-yymmdd-hhmmss" and we will be changing the extension to ".csv".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple shell loop to (carefully) rename the files as I think you're asking:

```
d=$(date +%y%m%d-%y%m%d-%H%M%S)
for f in Abc_*.*.*.*_*.txt
do
  new=${f%_*}_${d}.csv
  [ ! -f "$new" ] && mv "$f" "$new"
done
```

It first captures the timestamp, in the format you wrote, into a variable named `d`. It then loops over a simplistic glob format to pick up all files whose name starts with "Abc_" and then have anything between the three periods, followed by anything, then followed by an underscore and anything, and ending in ".txt".

It computes the new filename by stripping off everything (including and) after the last underscore, then appends the timestamp (`${d}`) and the new ".csv" extension.

If that new filename does *not* exist, then it will rename the file. Remove the `[ ! -f "$new" ] &&` part if you don't care about clobbering existing files.

Add in an `echo` before the `mv` if you want to see a dry-run of what it would do before actually executing it.

When I run it, I see:

```
$ touch Abc_10.11.76.112_001.txt Abc_192.168.1.164_001.txt Abc_54.78.1.1_002.txt
$ d=$(date +%y%m%d-%y%m%d-%H%M%S)
$ for f in Abc_*.*.*.*_*.txt; do new=${f%_*}_${d}.csv; [ ! -f "$new" ] && mv "$f" "$new"; done
$ ls -1
Abc_10.11.76.112_160913-160913-140649.csv
Abc_192.168.1.164_160913-160913-140649.csv
Abc_54.78.1.1_160913-160913-140649.csv
```

Comment: Most excellent. This is exactly what I need to accomplish. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

If by *date and time stamp*, you mean the modification time of the file, with `zsh` you could do:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
autoload zmv

zmv -n '(*_*_)*(.txt)' '$1$(zstat -F %FT%T%z +mtime -- $f)$2'
```

(remove `-n` to actually do the rename)

Note that for those `.txt` files that are symlinks, the time stamp is based on the modification time of the target of the symlink, not that of the symlink itself. Add the `-L` option to `zstat` to use the modification time of the symlink itself instead.

`%FT%T%z` gives an unambiguous local time stamp such as `2016-09-13T17:32:17+0100`. You can adapt to your need using standard `strftime()` format (same as with `date +<format>`). However note that `zsh`'s `zstat` doesn't support sub-second precision (for file systems that store modification times with sub-second precision).

If on a GNU system, you can use GNU `date -r` instead of `zstat` to get those nanoseconds:

```
$ zmv -n '(*_*_)*(.txt)' '$1$(date -r $f +%FT%T.%N%z)$2'
mv -- Abc_192.168.1.164_001.txt Abc_192.168.1.164_2016-09-13T17:32:17.368805094+0100.txt
```

Like for `zstat`, that takes the modification time of the *target* of the symlinks, not of the symlink itself. `date` has no option to use the mtime of the symlink, though you could use GNU `find` instead.

Comment: Appreciate your help. I'm still a newbie so this is a very good learning experience for me. Thank you.